# Passing PHP variable to Javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to pass a PHP variable to a Javascript function but it keeps displaying as 'undefined'. I have the Javascript on a separate page and am including it on the page that I am calling the function from. Here is the code:

```
<?php $repname    = $_SESSION['REPNAME']; ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chat.js"></script>

<input type="button" name="btn_send_chat" id="btn_send_chat" value="Send" onclick="javascript:sendChatText('<?php echo $repname;?>');" />
```

Here is js/chat.js:

```
function sendChatText(repname) {
    alert(repname);

        }
```

Comment: Have you called `session_start()` yet?

Comment: Yeah, I echo the variable successfully

Comment: Whats wierd is if I change the call to onclick="javascript:sendChatText("My Name"); it still says undefined. somethings wrong on the javascript side.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting $repid but echoing $repname

Comment: Oops, I am trying to only display relevant code and copied wrong variable

Comment: so the problem is still outstanding? If so double check you're not getting a 404 on your JS link.

Comment: yeah still outstanding.... no 404..

Comment: Honestly I can't see a problem with your code. You don't have any quotes inside the string that need escaping?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this isn't working but I got around it by adding that Javascript function to the PHP page and doing this:

```
var repName;
        function sendChatText() {
        repName = '<?php echo $repname;?>';
                    }
```